# How to schedule the airflow job with start_date and End_date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to schedule job which will dynamically run on daily basis with interval of 3 hours,start at 13:45 and end at 14:30 PM .
My code is as follows:

```
Test = datetime.now()

current_date = datetime.now()

default_args = {

'owner': 'abc',

'depends_on_past': False,

'start_date': datetime(Test.year, Test.month,Test.day, 13, 45),

'retries': 1,

'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),

'queue': 'bash_queue',

'end_date': datetime(Test.year, Test.month,Test.day,14,30),

}

dag = DAG('CSVDataFile', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=5))
```

not able to run with start_date and end_date , but it runs on normal 5 mintes interval,
please help in this Issue

Comment: What do you mean not able to run with start_date and end_date , but it runs on normal 5 mintes interval, please help in this Issue:

Does it not run at all, does it not stop at the end_date? or what happens?

Comment: it is not picking up my mentioned start_date , time and end_date,time , Just working picking interval ( with i mention as 5 mintues)  at scheduling

Comment: Still don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Airflow 1.8 above, please provide a fixed start_time based on Updating log: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#less-forgiving-scheduler-on-dynamic-start_date

 Also, try to make sure it is under UTC.

> Run your entire Airflow infrastructure in UTC. Airflow was developed at Airbnb, where every system runs on UTC (GMT)